# Find website Information

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, seo

I have been given task to 
check for url that

1. site:domain (If index in Google)
2. link:domain ( If any backlinks)
3. keyword (in domain)

Can anybody give me idea how to implement it.So far for 1 I think i should search google for the KW  site: `your site.com` and see if it is listed in the results or not.

2 and 3 are still unknown.

Any help would be great.

I have to use c# winforms or WPF.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want.  If understand correctly 1) is you want an app to do a request to see if a domain is in listed in google?    Perhaps you could try and do that one first?  http://www.vcskicks.com/download_file_http.php may help

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may come in handy: http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html